# Boost log crashes when disk full

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

Boost log causes my application to crash when I run out of disk space.

It also crashes if I open an active log file in excel and it tries to rollover the file when excel has it open.

It is pretty awful that my application crashes due to the logging. It should just fail silently. From the dump it looks like an unhandled exception.

How can I make it fail silently rather than crash my application?

I am using boost trvial logger and configuring it like so:

```
    boost::log::add_file_log(
        boost::log::keywords::file_name = "foo.log",
        boost::log::keywords::target = C:\\log",
        boost::log::keywords::rotation_size = 100000,
        boost::log::keywords::max_size = 10 * 100000,
        boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true,
        boost::log::keywords::format = "%TimeStamp%,%Message%",
        boost::log::keywords::time_based_rotation = boost::log::sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0)
    );
```

Comment: What exception? Thrown from where?

Comment: it thows in the logger when it tries to roll over the log files. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell boost log to suppress exceptions, like so:

```
boost::log::core::get()->set_exception_handler(boost::log::make_exception_suppressor());
```